# Overlapping multiple relative layouts in a framel ayout

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout, overlapping

Is it possible to overlap multiple relative layouts in a frame layout in android programmatically?

Or multiple relative layouts in a relative layout can be overlapped or not in android?

Comment: What happened when you tried to overlap multiple `RelativeLayouts`?

Comment: perhaps you can try using negative values for margin to achieve overlapping.  e.g. layout2 is aligned to right of layout1, but has -100dp left margin?